# How to get the image extension from a remote image url that doesn't contain image extension in the url

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the Image API to get the image data/extension for image urls.

I can easily use regex to the file extension from names like {domain}.com/path-to-image.jpg, but what about for image urls like: http://placekitten.com/g/1000/1000

I am trying to get a dataUrl for the image data at that location.
This is the particular part of code where this data is needed. You can see currently I am hard coding 'image/png'.

```
  _getDataUri(url, callback) {
    const props = this.props;
    const img = new Image();
    img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

    img.onload = function onLoadedImage() {
      const {minHeight, minWidth} = props.opt;
      const [width, height] = [img.width, img.height];

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = this.width;
      canvas.height = this.height;

      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

      const dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      callback({
        dataUrl,
        height,
        minHeight,
        minWidth,
        width
      });
    };

    img.onerror = function onImageError() {
      props.opt.onModalClose();
      props.opt.onChangeCardStatus('invalidImage');
    };

    img.src = url;
  }
```

*** Update ***
Fetch api will NOT solve this problem because it will not produce a readable response if you disable cors.

Comment: How do you successfully call `canvas.toDataURL()` without an error if the image is not served with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fetch()`, `Response.blob()`,  `FileReader.prototype.readAsDataURL()`

```
fetch("http://placekitten.com/g/1000/1000")
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
  console.log(blob.type);
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    console.log(reader.result)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob) 
})
```

Comment: So the drawback of using this technique is that fetch apparently still uses CORS, which doesn't effectively solve the problem of what I'm trying to utilize this for, whereas an image src shouldn't use CORS.

Do you have any ideas how to bypass this?

Comment: @Anchalee How do you call `.toDataURL()` at `javascript` at Question if the image is not served with CORS headers? If you can successfully call `canvas.toDataURL()` you should be able to use `canvas.toBlob()`, or `.toBlob()` with `FileReader()` to get the `MIME` type of image.